# How to store and retrieve data from bigquery to arduino using temboo?

Tags: arduino, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, temboo

I want to create a Internet of things project using [temboo](https://temboo.com/)

in that i use arduino as my device, temboo has a support to connect and store our sensor streaming data using google bigquery,here my scenario is set a threshold value in the bigquery table if it reaches that value ,it should trigger the information back to arduino, so i need to retrieve the data from bigquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think BigQuery has a callback mechanism back to your app. So, your app needs to use BigQuery API to periodically check for what it needs to check.